# Meta data about latex bibliography (which sources came from which journals, how old the publications are, etc)

Tags: bibliographies

I'm writing an annotated bibliography, and I was curious whether there's a latex package that could tell me statistics about my sources. Things like:

- a historgram of how old my sources are
- pie charts about how many of my sources came from which conferences or journals
- or even cooler, a connected-node graph that shows which sources cite/are cited by which of the other sources in my bibliography

I've looked online, but I haven't found any mention of something like this. Ideally, I'd like to just do something like:

```
\usepackage{metabiblio} % or whatever it's called
\addbibresource{filename.bib}
\nocite{*}
\dataonbib % this magically gives me a page of graphs about my bibliography
\printbibliography
```

But I've found nothing like this online, and I'm guessing I'd have to write a python script and do this myself, then manually add the graphs every time that I add new sources/re-run the code.

Comment: Not LaTeX directly. Try 'metaknowledge' (Python) or 'bibliometrix' (R). You can use LaTeX with R to produce a dynamic report with bibliometrix data.

Comment: The info for 1 and 2 is at least contained in most `.bib` files and so could in theory be extracted on the LaTeX side. I wouldn't do that since other languages offer more straightforward solutions for this, but if you insist on LaTeX it should at least be theoretically doable. The info for 3 isn't even present in most `.bib` files and so I don't see a way to produce it (and again, even though Ti*k*Z can produce graphs I probably wouldn't want to use LaTeX directly to produce these graphs).